# ST_Within,ST_IsValid or any other geos or rtreetopo related function not working in spatialite built for IOS plateform

Tags: ios, xcode, sqlite, makefile, spatialite

I have built spatialite for IOS using
https://github.com/mrclayman/libspatialite-ios/blob/libspatialite-5/Makefile makefile.

Included libraries in my app as follow

[image]

Added these to the search paths in your Xcode project's "Build Settings":

```
Library Search Paths: $(PROJECT_DIR)/AppName/libspatialite
Header Search Paths: $(PROJECT_DIR)/AppName/libspatialite/include
```

And in the "Build Phases" window, add the following to the section "Link Binary With Libraries":

```
libiconv
libcharset.1.0.0
libc++
libxml2.2
libz
```

Also added following in "Other Linker Flags"

```
-lsqlite3 -lproj -lgeos -lspatialite -lgeos_c
```

in Swift, included the headers in bridging header file:

```
#include <sqlite3.h>
#include <spatialite/gaiageo.h>
#include <spatialite.h>
```

and in my code i accessed the geopackage file and spatialite is working fine.

```
    var db: OpaquePointer?
    let flags = SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE
    if sqlite3_open_v2(databasePath, &db, flags, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        print("Spatialite database opened successfully")
        
        var spconnect: OpaquePointer?
        print("Spatialite version: \(spatialite_version()!)")
    }
```

I have tested a few geometry related functions like AsText , MakePoint etc and all spatialite based functions are working fine but when i try to run function which require other module like geos or proj for example

```
ST_IsValid , IsValidReason , ST_Within , ST_Overlaps , 
Throws error.

ST_IsValid returns -1 



SELECT ST_IsValid(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(15.785 21.713)'))

IsValidReason always throws error and ST_Within doesn't filter any record.
```

I have also tested another build by manually disabling a few functions for integrating rttopo module and any function which requires rttopo like

```
MakeValid or AsTWKB doesn't work.
```

Spatialite is properly built for

```
armv7,armv7s,arm64,i386,x86_64 architectures
```

but as per i understood it is not properly communicating with other modules.
Any type of help would be appereciated.